# How to count occurrences of date only in a field that contains datetime data?

Tags: mariadb

I have a MariaDB database/table that contains log entries. For the purpose of example and broader help to other users, let's call the table `FOO_TABLE` and the field `FOO_TIMESTAMP`.

The `FOO_TIMESTAMP` field had a data type of `datetime`.  Examples of content include:

```
select FOO_TIMESTAMP from FOO_TABLE limit 10;
+---------------------+
| FOO_TIMESTAMP       |
+---------------------+
| 2013-01-21 12:28:17 |
| 2013-02-06 08:54:05 |
| 2013-02-06 08:59:55 |
| 2013-02-06 09:05:46 |
| 2013-02-06 11:47:38 |
| 2013-02-06 12:14:04 |
| 2013-02-06 12:15:05 |
| 2013-02-06 12:42:45 |
| 2013-02-06 13:01:49 |
| 2013-02-06 13:20:50 |
+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to get a count of how many rows were created *per day*.  I'm not interested in the specific time.  So for example, I'd like the following information from the data set above:

```
2013-01-21     1
2013-02-06     9
```

I've searched prior stack exchange sites and see plenty of references to the `GROUP BY` option but I'm not sure how to only filter it on the date... and not have it look at the full time too.

I can get the date by itself by running `select date(FOO_TIMESTAMP) from FOO_TABLE;` but I still can't get a count of the occurrences of that.

I thought of trying something like `select date(FOO_TIMESTAMP) as DATEONLY from FOO_TABLE group by DATEONLY;`  but that still doesn't give me count of date occurrences.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like you need an aggregate function that counts rows per group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to format the timestamp so it only shows the day, then group by that:

```
select date_format(foo_timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d'), count(*)
from foo_table
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Comment: That works! Thank you.  Can you please explain what the `1` in `group by 1 order by 1` is? I want to make sure I understand this so I don't need to ask again. :-)

Comment: It just means it uses the first column